# spring cloud server.port not working with active profiles

Tags: spring, cloud, config

config server:
src\main\resources\configPath\cloud-config-repo\movie.yml:

```
---
spring:
  profiles: cloud
  jpa:
    show_sql: false
    database: MYSQL
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discovery-kb.cfapps.io/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: movie-kb.cfapps.io
    nonSecurePort: 80
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true
---
application:
  name: movie
spring:
  profiles: lattice
  jpa:
    show_sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  datasource:
    platform: hsqldb
server:
  port: 9006
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
  instance:
    hostname: ${vcap.application.uris[0]:localhost:9006}
    nonSecurePort: 80
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true
---
spring:
  profiles: development
  jpa:
    show_sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
server:
    port: 9005
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true
```

when i started move-service , Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http).
why not 9005?
move service :
src\main\resources\application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: development
```

Comment: How are you telling spring to consider `....\movie.yml`?

Comment: spring:
  application:
    name: movie